# Node JS: Compile .scss file to .css and .map.css via node js script

Tags: node.js, sass

I am new to node js, its structure and so on.

I am trying to compile a `.scss` file into a `.css` and `.map.css` file using a node js script.
The script `sass-dev.js` is defined in my `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    "sass-dev": "node ./scripts/sass-dev.js"
},
```

So I can run the script via `npm run sass-dev`. The script itself works correctly, so it compiles the `utility.scss` into `utility.css`. But I want also that a source map `utility.map.css` is created. Therefore I defined `sourceMap: true` in the options, but no additional file is created.

So, how can I compile a `.css` **and** `.map.css` file from my `.scss`?

`sass-dev.js`:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const sass = require('sass');

const sassFile = path.join(__dirname, '../sass/utility.scss').toString();
const cssFile = path.join(__dirname, '../css/utility.css').toString();
const mapFile = path.join(__dirname, '../css/utility.map.scss').toString();

sass.render(
    {
        file: sassFile,
        sourceMap: true,
        outFile: mapFile,
    },
    (error, result) => {
        if (!error) {
            fs.writeFileSync(cssFile, result.css, function (err) {
                if (err) console.log(`Error appeared while writing file "${o}".`);
            });
        } else {
            console.log(error.formatted);
            console.log(`Error appeared in "${error.file}" !\nline: ${error.line}, column: ${error.column}\n${error.status}`);
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In node-scss, setting the file paths will not automatically write the output to the file (both CSS and mappings), it is just used for references and you have to write the output to a file just like how you did for the CSS.

Also, `outFile` should be the path of the generated CSS file. If you set `sourceMap` to true, the map file will be automatically determined (by appending .map). Otherwise you can set `sourceMap` directly to a string to use that.

Finally, since you are using `writeFileSync`, you don't have to pass a callback function, simply wrap it around in try catch.

```js
sass.render({
    file: sassFile,
    outFile: cssFile,
}, (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
        // Handle error
        return;
    }

    try {
        fs.writeFileSync(cssFile, result.css);
        fs.writeFileSync(mapFile, result.map);
    } catch (e) {
        // Handle error
    }
});
```